# add unique anchors to regexp matches in text

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I use vbs regexp to highlight search matches in a text, and try to figure out how to combine the highlight spam with unique id anchor to for hyperlinking from a list of the matches.

I have tried a for  IncrementCount = 1 to match.count loop, but that return the total on all matches.

```
Function HighlightText(strInput,arrtext)
    Set re = New RegExp 
    re.Pattern="(?!<.*?)(" & arrtext & ")(?![^<>]*?>)" 
    re.IgnoreCase = True 
    re.Global = True
         if arrtext <> "" then 
         strOutput = re.Replace(strInput,"<span id="""&IncrementCount&""" style=""background-color:#FFD200;"">"&""&"$&</span>")
         Else
         strOutput = strInput
         end if
    HighlightText = strOutput
    set re = nothing
end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot get hold of a match number when using `RegExp.Replace` in vbScript. So, you have to use the `RegExp.Execute` method to get a collection of matches, then process each match yourself.

Here is some example code that I think does what you want. It uses regexp to give the match collection that identifies the places in the input string that need to be replaced, then uses standard vbScript functions `Left()` and `Mid()` to chop the string at right places and insert the required spans. Note that it processes the matches in reverse order, so that the chop/insert can use the indexes of the original match without worrying about what has already been replaced in the output string.

Also, note you might need to pre-process the match string if this is user-input, because the user may key in characters that are significant in a regular expression.

This is certainly not as efficient as using `RegExp.Replace` but it does provide the relevant unique IDs for each match.

```
'// Function finds all occurrences of a string 
'// (or multiple strings separated by |) within 
'// an input string, and places a <span> tag
'// with a unique numbered id around each occurrence
Function HighlightText(strInput,sFind)

    '// Don't do anything of no string to be found
    If len(sFind) = 0 then
        HighlightText = strInput
        Exit Function
    end If

    '// Define regexp
    Dim re
    Set re = New RegExp 

    '// Pattern to be found
    re.Pattern="(?!<.*?)(" & sFind & ")(?![^<>]*?>)" 
    re.IgnoreCase = True 
    re.Global = True

    '// find all the matches >> match collection
    Dim oMatches: Set oMatches = re.Execute( strInput )

    '// Prepare to process
    Dim sMatchedText
    Dim strOutput
    Dim oMatch
    Dim ix

    '// Initialize the output
    strOutput = strInput

    '// Process each match starting at the last one
    '// - this avoids needing to recalculate indexes
    '// after each replacement
    For ix = oMatches.Count -1 to 0 Step -1

        '// get the match
        Set oMatch = oMatches(ix)

        '// get the text that was matched
        sMatchedText = oMatch.SubMatches(0)

        '//DEBUG -- CONS.print "Match #" & ix & ": " & oMatch.Value & " At:" & cStr(oMatch.FirstIndex + 1)  & " Match:" & sMatchedText

        '// Replace the match in the output with the 
        '// required span tag, with unique match number as ID
        strOutput = Left(strOutput, oMatch.FirstIndex) & _
                    "<span id='MATCH#" & ix & "'>" & sMatchedText & "</span>" _
                    & Mid(strOutput, oMatch.FirstIndex + oMatch.length + 1)
    Next

    Set re = nothing

    '// Return the processed output
    HighlightText = strOutput

End Function
```